# Convert VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need a little help converting some VB.NET code to C#.  I have tried several "code converters" but none of them are giving me back a workable response.

Here's the code:

```
If Me.OrdersDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
Dim editForm As New Order(Me.NorthwindDataSet, _
    Me.NorthwindDataSet.Orders.Rows.IndexOf_
    (CType(CType(Me.OrdersDataGridView.SelectedRows(0)._
    DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row, NorthwindDataSet.OrdersRow)))
    editForm.Show()
End If
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: here's a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/DataGridViewEditForm.aspx?msg=2492346) to the original article I found this in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (this.OrdersDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    NorthwindDataSet.OrdersRow row = (NorthwindDataSet.OrdersRow)
                                       ((DataRowView)this.OrdersDataGridView
                                            .SelectedRows(0).DataBoundIte).Row;

    Order editForm = new Order(
                           this.NorthwindDataSet,
                           this.NorthwindDataSet.Orders.Rows.IndexOf(row));

    editForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: Andrew I could be wrong but I think you have the VB style index for SelectedRows and you left off the m for DataBoundItem. But hopefully he can figure that out after trying it once and having it fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.OrdersDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    Order editForm = new Order(this.NorthwindDataSet,
        this.NorthwindDataSet.Orders.Rows.IndexOf((NorthwindDataSet.OrdersRow)((DataRowView)this.OrdersDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).Row);
    editForm.Show();
}
```

Ok I think I typed that correct.

Answer (score 0):

If code converters are failing here, it's likely because you need a reference in your Visual Studio solution to that specific database in order for it to work.

The conversion should be something like:

```
if (this.OrdersDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    var dataRowView = (DataRowView) this.OrdersDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).DataBoundItem;
    var ordersRow = (NorthwindDataSet.OrdersRow) dataRowView;
    var editForm = new Order(this.NorthwindDataSet, ordersRow)
    editForm.Show()
}
```